# Get String from Cmd.exe C#

Tags: c#

Lets say i got a .bat file, where the text is like
echo HELLO
pause

That outputs "HELLO".
nothing else

If i start the process from C#, maybe i want to idle on the process and put everything it outputs to a string?
Like i scan the process.

I got code, that does this, but after like 0 seconds, when process is started, it takes what it outputs, but only the first.
If i got a bat file with 100 lines then it only takes 1 maybe.

Alltogether, As soon when a bat file outputs anything new, i want to get it in my C# app.

Please help

Sample code:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Users\WS\Desktop\Modded\"); 
Process p = new Process(); 
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\WS\Desktop\Modded\Launcher.bat"; 
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
p.Start(); 
txtLog.Text = 
p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 
p.Close();
```

~~ redpois0n

Comment: Show us your current code. (How to prepare sample code: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: Ill add now....

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(@"C:\Users\WS\Desktop\Modded\");
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\WS\Desktop\Modded\Launcher.bat";

            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.Start();
            
            txtLog.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.Close();

Comment: @user841016: Don't put it in the comment, where it's hidden and unreadable - put it in the *question*.

Comment: Looks fine so far, except that I'd call `p.WaitForExit()` before `p.Close()` (but I think that's unrelated to your problem). Can you create a short, simple bat file that reproduces the problem using this code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, it should return a string array and it sounds like you are only retrieving/displaying the first element of the array. If the command line has many arguments you need to just loop through the array from 0 until the size of the array.

Also the txtLog may need to be changed to:
        txtLog.Text += p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
if you are appending to the log.

Comment: Yes thats right, but it is a minecraft server, that "generates" new strings anytime. Like BLLALBLALB joined the game. 
And if i DONT put p.Close(); it will not return anything.
and a loop in p.StandardOutPut.ReadToend() wont work either, i want a live stream

Comment: You can loop p.StandardOutPut.ReadLine(); rather than "readToend();"

Comment: Yes, but  i have to call p.Stop(); to get something out of that

Comment: Then you need asynchronous output which you can find out how to do here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx